# What does the ! mean in user preferences?

Tags: customization

I want to enable the export option with the ! next to it, but I want to know if it's safe. Can you please tell me what the object with the circle over it means in user preferences? [image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a support level warning icon.

That generally means it is an experimental, community contribution, or "work-in-progress" under development addon or extension, not officially supported or endorsed by the Blender foundation, as opposed to official addons, or stable fully supported ones, I think.

Generally means use at your own discretion, though most likely no harm will come from it.